# ASP.NET Core 2.2 SignalR does not connect to hosting

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, handshake

My ASP.NET Core 2.2 chat application works fine when I connect to server and open in on server browser, but when I try to connect from client I got this error:

**Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.'
Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.
signalr.js:1760 POST http://XXXXX.com/chatHub?id=YbE0yZSEJwTDRt0FIXw01Q 404 (Not Found)**

Turning off Windows Firewall not worked

Adding these codes not worked:

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    //.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true) //for signalr cors                
            );
        });
```

AND

```
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
```